# UITableViewController, Storyboards and UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to create a UI just like Facebook's comment screen on mobile.

I got a UITableViewController on my storyboard. I need to insert a view docked to the bottom of the screen to place a text field. Since the tableview is taking the full screen, I can't do it on storyboard and I think I need to do it programmatically but how? Should I modify the constraints that stretch the tableview to the edges and insert the views or what?

Thanks.

Comment: In Comment Screen, You take tableViewController is fine and add at footer of tableview comment box. so that all is easy for you.

Comment: agree with @KiritModi and other option is to create a UIViewController instead of UITableViewController and add TableView inside a UIViewController and take another UIView and place it at the end of UIViewController.

Comment: see The demo : https://github.com/bmancini55/iOSExamples-DockedKeyboardView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add table view to normal `UIViewController` and below it add another view.

Comment: This prevents me from using pull to refresh feature, right?

Comment: Ok, so in that case you can try to use `tableFooterView` of `UITableView` property and `UITableViewController` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView